# How to add custom components into Ant Design stepper?

Tags: reactjs, antd, stepper

I'm new to AntD and having a little trouble with the stepper component - specifically, how to add a custom component into each of the steps.

For example,

```
const steps = [
  {
    title: 'First',
    content: 'First-content',
  },
  {
    title: 'Second',
    content: 'Second-content',
  },
  {
    title: 'Last',
    content: 'Last-content',
  },
];
```

For simplicity, if I were to use the Autocomplete component would it be just:

```
{
  title: 'First',
  content: '<Autocomplete />',
},
```

No luck so far. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `content` in [`Steps.Step`](https://ant.design/components/steps/#Steps.Step).

You may be trying to render a custom component in `Steps`, then you need to provide `ReactNode` and not a `string` type:

```
<Steps>
  <Steps.Step> title="Finished" description={<AutoComplete/>} />
</Steps>
```

Its all mentioned [in the docs](https://ant.design/components/steps/), I believe what you need is the [basics of React.](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you found this official example [Switch Step](https://ant.design/components/steps/#components-steps-demo-step-next), there is a `steps` variable like this:

```js
const steps = [
  {
    title: 'First',
    content: 'First-content',
  },
  {
    title: 'Second',
    content: 'Second-content',
  },
  {
    title: 'Last',
    content: 'Last-content',
  },
];
```

This is a user-defined variable, **NOT pre-defined by antd**, you can use whatever property even data structure you want. You can assign the `ReactNode` to `content` property like:

```js
const steps = [
  {
    title: 'First',
    content: <Autocomplete />,
  },
  // ...
]
```

And render the `content` based on current step state:

```
<div className="steps-content">{steps[current].content}</div>
```

There is **NO** `content` prop for the `Steps.Step` component. This is another way different from the accepted answer.